# threejs point cloud geometry rotation to itself

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

I have created a geometry using some x,y,z positions. Now I have to rotate this geometry to its self axis i.e. it should rotate like earth is rotating. I don't want camera to be moved but I want  geometry to be moved.
Can Someone help? The code right now is something like:
var myGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   vertex.x = green_arr[i];
   vertex.y = green_arr[i+1];
   vertex.z = green_arr[i+2];
   myGeometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}
var particleCube = new THREE.PointCloud( myGeometry, shaderMaterial );
particleCube.dynamic = true;
particleCube.sortParticles = true;
scene.add( particleCube );
```

I have for rotation

```
var time = Date.now() * 0.0004;
scene.children[0].rotation.y = time;
scene.children[0].rotation.z = time * 0.7;
```

But this is rotating my points all over the screen which I don't want. I want to rotate them around its own axis

Answer (score 0):

Are  you trying to rotate each vertex around it's own local position? Or around the PointCloud's position?

It looks like your current code rotates the whole system around its origin.
If you want each point rotating around it's own local axis you might try adding them to their own separate array and looping through that in the render function:

```
for(var p=0; p<particleCube.geometry.length; p++){
     particleCube.geometry.vertices[p].rotation.y=time;
     particleCube.geometry.vertices[p].rotation.z=time*0.7;
}
```

Otherwise you might try

`particleCube.rotation.y=time;
 particleCube.rotation.z=time*0.7;`

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply 
I have code which is something like this 

    http://jsfiddle.net/r7ocy1ff/

This one is not working right now 

I want rotation of the geometry of point cloud like the arcball rotation.
I tried with quaternion, also rotation along the axis but this one is not what I want the rotation along the axis is working for me but that is not rotating 360 degrees. also the rotation should be only on mouseup/down.

Comment: Hi I could get that going rotate along the axis which is working fine for me now. Now Can anyone help me to achieve this on mouse move since this rotate only rotates in one direction may be is is 360 degrees but still  I cannot control it on mousemove